# Hive: Resources added using script getting cleared in Hortonworks?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

If I execute

```
hive -f <my_sql_script>
```

to do some stuff in which i first add some resources i need like:-

```
add jar my.jar;
add file myfile;
// create function and execute query using that function
```

This works fine when i execute the whole script from outside(not entering hive using hive command). But when entering the hive interpreter  and i try to execute my query using the function Ii created is doesn't find the function. So i have to again add jar and files in the hive terminal i entered using hive command. Then it works.

So my question here is that is there a new session of hive being opened? As the resources added by me from outside hive are lost?

In case of **MapR** and **Cloudera** this was not the case. I added the resources from outside using hive -f  and after entering hive also i was able to execute my query using the function i created in the script. So why such behavior in **Hortonworks**?

Comment: did you try loading jar into HDFS and add it into the HIVE or wherever you want ?

Comment: No i have the JAR in the Linux FS not HDFS. Not sure where hive puts it when we use the add jar command, but i read somewhere and i think it in the distributed cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Hortonworks, and you need to add the file/jar within the same session - as you have discovered.

Comment: So seems like this is the way to go. Strange it works in MapR and Cloudera. Is the same session being used in case of MapR and CDH?

Comment: I have not used those distros sufficiently to comment on them. In any case I learned my habits within Apache (which is similar in behavior to  HW) : so it never occurred to me to attempt to access resources that had not been defined within the present session.